# What should I do with these manuscripts?

Tags: jewish-books, yeshiva-school, manuscripts

My great grandfather learned in many big European yeshivos.

I recently obtained from his nephew 7 notebooks he wrote of shiurim he heard from R' Baruch Ber, R' Ahron Kotler, R' Shimon Shkopp, and R' Avraham Yaffin.

Besides for handing them down as an heirloom, what should I do with them? Maybe they contain yet unpublished shiurim? Sell them to a collector (how much would they go for?)? I feel like I should do something - it feels weird keeping such weighty articles on an end table in the living room (it is a safe place).

(His name was R' Aryeh Leib Gurevich. He founded a yeshiva in Rio de Janeiro called Gur Aryeh. He died in his 30s from cancer, but had already developed a group of loyal talmidim who followed him to Rio.)

Comment: Donate them to a library (YU, Penn, YIVO, JNUL, etc plenty of good options) who will digitize them

Comment: are you asking about the specific notebooks, or the content? You can type up the shiurim and get it bound if your concern is what is in there.

Comment: Connect https://alehzayis.com/ they could help you publish them. They do high quality work

Answer (score 4):

1. Make copies
2. Find someone sitting in kolel or a younger student who’d like to make some extra money
3. Pay them to transcribe the hand written notes into text
4. Optionally, but ideally, find a Talmid Chacham who can write up a background to the lectures, summaries, etc. Perhaps compare the notes existing recorded shiurim by the same rabbis.
5. Whether or not you do step 4, publish them.

You can also find what tractate the yeshivas are learning this year, find shiurim from those tractates, transcribe and publish them as pamphlets, distribute them to those yeshivot and ask for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are many publishers who might be interested. Those are all highly influential Rabbis and people would definitely be interested in reading them. A publisher could probably organize the notes into a nice book and publish them for a profit.